# Overstayed in Greece earlier. How can I return now?

Tags: visas, greece, overstaying

I am student in Greece but I didn't get student visa and overstayed about 20 days after the 90 day limit on my visa.

I got a black stamp on my list for entering (because I am Non EU citizen we are entering in Greece with papers that they give us on the border with entry and exit stamps). I was also fined 650 euros and was told that I cannot enter Greece within the next 3 months.

I want to apply for a visa now and wish to enter again in Greece before those 3 months pass. Can I do that?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question.  Are you saying that you overstayed in Greece, you were forbidden from entering for 3 months, but you want to apply for a visa to enter within that time anyway?  You can certainly apply, but my guess is it will be denied.

Comment: What's a “black stamp on my list for entering”? A stamp in your passport?

Answer (score 2):

You can always apply for a long-stay visa. I don't know about Greek law or practice but there is nothing that would preclude it in the Schengen regulations. Of course, you would also need a legitimate claim to this long-stay visa. Depending on the visa you are seeking, having overstayed before might weight against your application (even after the 3 months have passed) and it could take a few months anyway so it's unlikely to be a solution to return to Greece quickly.

You *cannot* enter without a visa for a short-stay because you already used your 90 days. In fact, you could not do it even if you did not overstay and left on the 90th day, which is why this 3-month thing does not sound like an actual ban but only like a reminder of the rules.